# iFrame background image problem on IE8

Tags: html

Hi i am trying since so long for background image on iframe its working fine on firefox and other browsers but serious problem i am facing on IE. Its showing nothing on IE. Pls help me out.
Here is my code:
I am using IE8.

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"  name="main" style="width:100%;height:90%; background-image:url(img/bg2.jpg)"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the background to the page you are loading inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on, but a couple things you could try are:

1. Add `clear: both;` to your css
2. Insert a div that contains everything within the iFrame and set the background on that.

Answer (score 0):

tyr this:

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" src="img/bg1.jpg" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"  name="main" style="width:100%;height:90%;"> </iframe>
```

I have putted image in src attribute now its working fine.